# Tag merge request: [acs] and [accesscontrolservice]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I was looking for information on this topic and found the duplicated tags [accesscontrolservice](/questions/tagged/accesscontrolservice) and [acs](/questions/tagged/acs). The [wiki for acs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/acs/info) confirms they should be the same tags.

Please merge and create the synonyms for these. Suggest that the master tag should be hyphenated as [access-control-service](/questions/tagged/access-control-service).

Comment: Here I was thinking ACS related to OpenACS, which is a content management system IIRC.

Comment: @DonalFellows: There's a good reason to sort these tags out ;)

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use the tag

- [acs](/questions/tagged/acs)

as a general tag for

- access control service

**Note:**

- You would tag an Azure specific topic with [azure](/questions/tagged/azure) and [acs](/questions/tagged/acs).

In case there is a need of a specific *azure acs* tag, I propose

- [azure-acs](/questions/tagged/azure-acs)

As a result I propose to merge the tag

- [accesscontrolservice](/questions/tagged/accesscontrolservice)

to

- [acs](/questions/tagged/acs) (in case the topic is not related to *azure*)

or

- [azure-acs](/questions/tagged/azure-acs) (in case the topic is related to *azure acs*)